# Vue "TypeError This is Undefined" when calling function from button @click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typeerror, web-frontend

I am currently learning vue and decided to make a simple D&D character sheet. I am currently working on a saving throws component and I am passing the character object it:

```
const character = ref({
  name: '',
  race: '',
  class: '',
  player: '',
  alignment: '',
  proficiencyBonus: 2,
  speed: "30ft",
  stats: {
    "Strength": {score: 10, proficiency: false},
    "Dexterity": {score: 10, proficiency: false},
    "Constitution": {score: 13, proficiency: false},
    "Wisdom": {score: 10, proficiency: false},
    "Intelligence": {score: 10, proficiency: false},
    "Charisma": {score: 10, proficiency: false}
  }
})
```

In the component I am using the ul tag and li tags to iterate over the stats:

```
        <ul class="ul">
            <li v-for="(key,value) in character.stats">
                <input v-model="character.stats[value].proficiency" type="checkbox" />
                <input v-model="character.stats[value].score" type="number" placeholder="0" min="1" max="30" class="fieldset-input-number" />
                <label>{{(getModifier(key) >= 0 ? "+":"") + getModifier(key)}}</label>
                <button @click="savingThrow(value)" class="fieldset-button">{{value}}</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

In the script setup tag I have a function named getModifier(score):

```
function getModifier(score) {
    const prof = score.proficiency ? this.props.character.proficiencyBonus:0
    return Math.floor((score.score - 10) / 2) + prof;
}
```

And the calls to the function from the label tag work properly. The modifier is displayed in the label and dynamically updates as I change the number in the numberbox and even adds the proficiencyBonus when I check the checkbox.

The problem is in the savingThrow(value) function used in the @click event for the buttons:

```
function savingThrow(key) {
    const roll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
    const mod = getModifier(this.props.character.stats[key]);
    console.log(`${key}: ${roll}+${mod} = ${roll+mod}`);
}
```

When I click the button and the proficiency checkbox is unchecked the function works fine, however when proficiency is true, meaning that it takes the true outcome of the "if" in getModifier(), it tries to access the this.props.character.proficiencyBonus and throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined
    getModifier Stats.vue:15
    savingThrow Stats.vue:10
    onClick Stats.vue:28
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164
    invoker runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:366
    addEventListener runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:316
    patchEvent runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:334
    patchProp runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:398
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4603
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4566
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4486
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4594
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4566
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4486
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    processFragment runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4856
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4482
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4594
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4566
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4486
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4594
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4566
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4486
    componentUpdateFn runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5037
    run reactivity.esm-bundler.js:167
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4939
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4897
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4489
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4594
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4566
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4486
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4685
    processFragment runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4856
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4482
    componentUpdateFn runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5037
    run reactivity.esm-bundler.js:167
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4939
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4897
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4489
    render2 runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5641
    mount runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3877
    mount runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1590
    <anonymous> main.js:4
```

So my question is why is the this.props.character.proficiencyBonus variable undefined when calling from the button event, when it works fine when called from the template v-for?

PS for clarity, I have already made sure that the character object is being passed into the component properly, and I have logged the value of the object I am passing into the getModifier function and it had the expected value.

Comment: "In the script setup tag " - you use composition api, don't you? Don't use `this` then, it doesn't make sense there

Comment: Yes, I am using the composition api. Also why not? It seems like the simplest way to access the character prop in the function.

Comment: Because `this` context isn't used in composition api, one of its purposes is to get rid of it.

Comment: Ok, fair. What would be the alternative way of accessing the character prop in the function then if not through this?

Comment: It's not alternative way but the only correct one, it's surely described in the docs because that's the official source of information. You didn't show the full code. If you use `script setup` syntax, it's defineProps

Comment: I have used defineProps since I am passing my character object from my main app to the component. The issue is that I cannot access the prop in the rest of the setup script. I have tried googling and looking at docs and didn't find a clear answer. Especially as to why this.props.character only works in certain cases. This is my first time getting into js and web-frontend. I am currently at work but if it helps I can provide the full code tonight.

Comment: this.props will work in parts that use options api, since composition and options can be combined, this is possible but not recommended. If you're new to this, try to stick to relevant composition examples. I can't recommend `script setup` for this because it's a made-up syntax and not proper JS and requires to know what really happens behind this syntax to effectively use it. Consider focusing on `script` with 100% composition api